# Restrict uses permission internet to a sole activity rather than the whole application

Tags: java, android, xml

I am not that good with android manifest. Could someone tell me if it is possible to restrict this uses permission below to a sole activity rather the whole application itself. The reason I ask this is to prevent my app as a whole(aside from that one activity) to be not be reliant on the internet. Also if I were to remove this code from the manifest my activity that needs this would always crash on start.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: You're really asking a non-question, as your premises are incorrect. Requesting a *permission* does *not* mean that your app won't run if there's no internet. You still have to check whether you have connectivity wherever it is needed. Regardless, permissions are for the entire app, not that it matters.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can add activity specific permissions. In fact, there doesn't exist a thing like activity specific permissions. Permissions are always defined at your application level.

What you should do is, check in your activities whether internet is available or not, and if it's not, write a separate flow so that your activity behaves normally.

Function to check if the device is connected :

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());

}
```